# Typescript RXjs version 6.6.0, issue with typing in subscription

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs

Have tried the following syntax:

```
   const s1 = new subject()

    s1.subscribe({
        next: (value) => {},
        error: (value) => {},
        complete: (value) => {},
    });
```

I get the following error:

Failed to compile.

> src/app/services/data/data-bank-service/data-bank.service.ts:40:57 -
> error TS2554: Expected 2-3 arguments, but got 1.
>
> 40
> s1.subscribe({
> ~~~~~~~~~~~  41             next: (value) => {},
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ ...   43             complete: (value) => {},
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~  44         });
> ~~~~~~~~~~
>
> node_modules/rxjs/internal/Observable.d.ts:51:39
> 51     subscribe(next: null | undefined, error: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
> An argument for 'error' was not provided.

Now I know that there was a new syntax for passing in callbacks

From `subscribe(callback, callback ,callback)` to `subscribe({next: callback, error: callback, complete: callback})`

but I can't seem to implement it properly. Any suggestions?

Example from website

http://reactivex.io/rxjs/manual/overview.html#subject

Comment: Maybe it's because `complete` doesn't receive any value and should be just `complete: () => {},`. If not then create a reproducible demo.

Comment: @martin that was actually it, thanks didn't consider that!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

martin correctly states in a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67518553/typescript-rxjs-version-6-6-0-issue-with-typing-in-subscription#comment119340929_67518553) that the culprit is the wrong type of `complete`: it should be `() => void`, not `(value: unknown) => void`.

I wanted to explain why the error is presented this way.

The method in question, `subscribe`, is [implemented in RxJS](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/881cacdc99a7ebae219b595004c632f7358f730d/src/internal/Observable.ts#L73-L80) with an overloaded signature.

```
  subscribe(observer?: PartialObserver<T>): Subscription;
  /** @deprecated Use an observer instead of a complete callback */
  subscribe(next: null | undefined, error: null | undefined, complete: () => void): Subscription;
  /** @deprecated Use an observer instead of an error callback */
  subscribe(next: null | undefined, error: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
  /** @deprecated Use an observer instead of a complete callback */
  subscribe(next: (value: T) => void, error: null | undefined, complete: () => void): Subscription;
  subscribe(next?: (value: T) => void, error?: (error: any) => void, complete?: () => void): Subscription;
```

When you call this method, TypeScript looks at the overloads in order (from top to bottom).

The object that OP attempted to pass in was

```
{
  next: (value) => {},
  error: (value) => {},
  complete: (value) => {},
}
```

whose signature was at first inferred as follows.

```
{
  next: (value: unknown) => void,
  error: (value: unknown) => void,
  complete: (value: unknown) => void,
}
```

Inferring the intended types of `unknown`s would happen only after (and if) the type checker finds a matching overload for this argument in `subscribe` method.

As Typescript tries to do this, it checks the first signature. It accepts a `PartialObserver`, which is basically

```
{
  closed?: boolean;
  next?: (value: T) => void;
  error?: (err: any) => void;
  complete?: () => void;
}
```

where at least one of `next`, `error` or `complete` must be present (see [here](https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/881cacdc99a7ebae219b595004c632f7358f730d/src/internal/types.ts#L71-L92) for details).

But the object provided by OP doesn't fit, because `complete` is of wrong type. TypeScript **silently ignores this** in some versions, and skips to a next overload. I emphasize this because this is the key of the confusion.

As TypeScript keeps going downwards, it fails to match different signatures for different reasons. Without knowing the exact TS version used by OP it's impossible to tell how exactly the error will be reported. [When I run a similar example in 4.2.3](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoFcBGBnBVgAOYwA9iMgN7IC+AULaJLIigApxTFwA2A8jtABu0ADwAVAHyVayWXITcS2CABMA-AC5kmEiW4Q4IANwzkICAA8wm5AApBPdBC1iAlMgC8UwSWAqTstBQJFA2tkFahgCe7l7IPn4ByAgkALYE+pBhsd6+-rR0tDDoIAjEZMjYWLj4mBDiErYkAlDCoVrsnMA8-MqtopKuWhg4eITlxqayxaUTldVjdQ225lZaIOjc3MgAPsglKhAwoKoANMhBIeub23sHRycq5ynpmc52OfF5Q2gL+ESkSZyZAzMqA+ajWr1SQrSxga5bXb7ECHY7mJ4XKDBKBacJYq7IaKfBIYl4ZCBZXHE77DP7jQFJaYlMEVKqQ4BLGGreF2BzcJwual+c6XHFmG5I+5os7JNLkyBUzy5Pw-EY1elkRkg5lzNnqzmNblhPkC5BuJVfYWY7FhUWREAxC0k55yt7ZJ0037sgGaqba2bgvWLaGNAB04Y4AHNsPaogBtAC6qrpPvIFFoUAp6CgabowMKwKDUNs6eBwO5uJNEE+FGopz9wLtvMc1YttfrZfkrop73sLZrdb91FcUyAA), I get the error TS2769, which is much clearer than TS2554 which the OP got:

```
No overload matches this call.
  Overload 1 of 5, '(observer?: PartialObserver<unknown> | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Type '(value: any) => void' is not assignable to type '() => void'.
  Overload 2 of 5, '(next?: ((value: unknown) => void) | undefined, error?: ((error: any) => void) | undefined, complete?: (() => void) | undefined): Subscription', gave the following error.
    Argument of type '{ next: (value: unknown) => void; error: (value: any) => void; complete: (value: any) => void; }' is not assignable to parameter of type '(value: unknown) => void'.
      Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'next' does not exist in type '(value: unknown) => void'.
```

It's still not perfect, because it doesn't really explain why would overloads 3, 4 and 5 fail, but it could improve in the future.

Takeaway: if the error makes no sense to you, try seeing what the other overloads are and "evaluate" them yourself in order.